# What does curruption in transmission(or bt in general) mean?

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

I use Transmission for bt downloading. I notice that many of my downloads has data corruption. But it doesn't report any error if I verify local data and I don't have problem playing the videos downloaded. What does this corruption really mean?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it means **transmission** downloaded corrupted data and upon  *checksum verification*, get rid of that data and redownload it.

So in the end, you don't see any corrupted data because it has been redownloaded.